# Taking value from one column to another-coding it differently

Tags: string, dataframe

I have a column in a data frame called 'personality types' (ENFP, ESFP, ISFP, ISTJ, etc). I would like to make another column 'introvert/extrovert' where I am taking the previous and classifying them based on the 'E' (extrovert) or the 'I'(introvert) in the acronym. I have dropped all NA's from the column and have tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
df['introvert/extrovert']=df['personality types'].str.contains('E', case = False), 'introvert/extrovert'] = 'extrovert'

df['introvert/extrovert]=df['personality types'].str.contains('I', case = False), 'introvert/extrovert] = 'introvert'
```

I expected a dataframe with a new column (introvert/extrovert) based on the strings in the personality type column.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.